# Understanding why join works differently

Tags: python, list

I would like some further insight in how the function `join()` works differently when using `format()`, and a list. As you can tell in the bottom, output is very different.

```
ina = "{a}{aa}{aaa}{aaaa}".format(a = "This ", aa = "is ", aaa = " my", aaaa = " house.")
print("=".join(ina))

list = "_".join(["Mayor in", "is the", "one to, done"])
print(list)
```

OUTPUT:

```
T=h=i=s= =i=s= = =m=y= =h=o=u=s=e=.
Mayor in_is the_one to, done
```

Comment: If you define `ina = 'This is  my house.'` you get the same behaviour. So `format` doesn't play a role here. Simplified example: Compare the output of `'='.join('AaZz')` and `'='.join(['Aa', 'Zz'])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ina = "{a}{aa}{aaa}{aaaa}".format(a = "This ", aa = "is ", aaa = " my", aaaa = " house.")
```

`ina` is now a string: `"This is my house"`.

```
"=".join(ina)
```

takes every element of the iterable `ina`, which is a character, and joins it using `=`.

```
["Mayor in", "is the", "one to, done"]
```

is a list.

```
"_".join(["Mayor in", "is the", "one to, done"])
```

takes every element of the iterable `["Mayor in", "is the", "one to, done"]`, which is a string, and joins it using `_`.

Joining a string (with character as elements) and joining a list (with strings as elements) will typically give different results, unless your list happens to have single characters in it.

---

As an aside, using `list` as a variable name in Python is a bad practice: `list` already [has a value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list). Should some other place in code use `list` intending to access the list type, the code would fail.

Answer (score -2):

This is because strings are stored as lists of characters. In the first example, ina = "This is my house." which behind the scenes is stored as ['T', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'm', 'y', ' ', 'h', etc.], so join inserts the '=' between each element of the array giving the output you saw.

The second example where you have a list of strings (aka a list of lists of characters) is stored as [['M', 'a', 'y', 'o', 'r', ' ', 'i', 'n'], ['i', 's', ' ', t', 'h', 'e'], ['o', ...]]. join() only operates on the outermost list, so it will only insert '_' in 2 places.

One way you can see this is by using the len() function.

len(ina) would be 18, but len(["Mayor in", "is the", "one to, done"]) would be 3.

Comment: No, strings are not stored as lists of characters. A string gives you single characters when you iterate over it.